# How to get the task number and id not the executor in storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to know what method to use to get the task information，not the executor information。And i can make the executor number > task number ,it seems the task number is useless。

I have used the `getComponentTasks()` in `Topologycontext` but I can only get the executors。

Anyone can help me？

Comment: What kind of task information do you want go get exactly?

Comment: I want get the id of all the tasks..

Comment: use the getComponentTasks() it return a list of executor id. but i want to get the real task id of the component..

Comment: Are you sure that it returns executor IDs and not task IDs? Do you have different number of executors than tasks?

Comment: yes,i set parallelism to 5,setTaskNumber(10)..it only return 5 taskid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
List<Integer> taskIds = context.getComponentTasks(context.getThisComponentId());
```

to receive all task IDs of your current component. If you want to get all task IDs over the whole topology, you need to collect them per component and put all of them together:

```java
List<Integer> taskIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(String compId : context.getComponentIds()) {
    taskIds.addAll(context.getComponentTasks(compId));
}
```

Comment: I know this, it seems returned the executor id。for example, i set the component's parallelism to 5，it return 5 taskid。 but setTaskNumber(10).

Comment: context.getComponentCommon(<ComponentID>).get_parallelism_hint() return the executor number.  The executors will dead, but  tasks never change?

Comment: I am not sure if you can get the number of task right now. The method name is definitely not a good choice. I will start a discussion at the Storm dev mailing list. Are you subscribed so you can follow the discussion?

Comment: Right now, the only idea I have is to collect the task information (ie, the number of tasks per operator) when to plug your topology together (ie, call `setNumTasks(...)` and hand it to your topology via the `Config` object you can provide via `StormSubmitter.submitTopology(...)`.

Comment: I do not subscribe to this yet。 Why the use the method name of task ,but return the executor。And the setNumtasks() seems needless...

Comment: Just go an answer on the mailing list. The method should work as intended. Not sure why it does not give the correct information in your case. See the thread in the mail archive (answer is still missing there, but should show up shorty) https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-dev/201512.mbox/%3C56715E34.7030407%40apache.org%3E

Comment: ok, thanks ,i have already subscribed the mail list and waiting for the answer!

Comment: sorry , i find i use the  jstorm.   storm is no problem. but when i use jstorm，this problem arise

Comment: I am not familiar with JStorm... I guess my answer is correct for Storm thought... Maybe you should open a new question.

Comment: yes,in storm you are right. should i close this question,and open another one for jstorm?

Comment: you can just leave this as is and open an new one for JStorm (maybe tag with "jstorm" and "apache-storm" tag, as JStorm is going to be part of Apache Storm in near future)

Answer (score 2):

A task ID is a single integer.  An executor ID is a range of task IDs.  1, 2, 3 are Task IDs.  If there were an executor that was running all three of these tasks its ID would be [1, 3] Which is a clojure persistent vector with the low task ID as the first element and the high task ID as the second one.

Matthias J. Sax is right context.getComponentTasks(compId) will return the complete set of Task IDs for that particular component.

Unless you do something special the number of executors is very likely to match the number of tasks.  In that case the executor IDs would look like [1, 1], [2, 2] and [3, 3].  You can adjust the number of executors per component using the rebalance command or rebalance method of the Nimbus Thrift client.

There is no way that I know of to get the number of executors for a component through the TopologyContext.  We could add one in if you need it, just file a JIRA under the STORM component in http://issues.apache.org/jira You can currently get that information by getting a TopologySummary from nimbus, but that is rather ugly, especially because all of the information is already in the process you are running in, it is just not exposed to you.

If you think getComponentTasks is returning something incorrect, please file a JIRA as a bug with a reproducible use case so we can debug/fix it for you.

Comment: sorry , i find i use the jstorm. storm is no problem. but when i use jstorm，this problem arise

Answer (score 0):

According to the post from apache-dev-list, you are using JStorm rather than Storm, right?

In JStorm, there's no executor, so TopologyContext.getComponentTasks() returns task ids within this component.

As to the answer to questions in the mail (I answered the mail), if you don't mind, I'll just paste it here as a reference for you:

> do tasks actually have an ID?

in JStorm, each task has an taskId of Integer type. Usually, each component is assigned a range of task id's (the num is equal to component parallelism)

> if yes, can those IDs be retrieved?

Yes, use TopologyContext.getThisTaskId() method

> can we get at least the number of tasks per operator somehow?

Yes, use TopologyContext.getComponentTasks().size()

> should the above method get renamed?

We may discuss this when merging phase starts. You may refer to related jira later.

Comment: in jstorm the method setTasksNumber seems useless! and the taskid correspond to the threadid

Comment: In JStorm the task num is set in TopologyBuilder like this: 

`builder.setBolt('Your_Bolt_Name', new YourBolt(), bolt_parallelism_hint)
` and we don't have a setTasksNumber method... I don't get you about taskid correspond to the threadid either. Are you sure you're refering JStorm?

Comment: It seems in jstorm one task correspond one executor. And are tasks in JStorm static? When we do a rebanlance , the tasknumber won't be changed?

Comment: Task num **may be** changed after rebalance, as well as corresponding task id's, since rebalance typically changes the parallelism of your components.